# Is there a short symbology to express that $f$ is a morphism in $C$?

Tags: category-theory, convention

For the simple purpose of taking notes without writing too much, I'm wandering two things.

Given the category $C$

- is it ok to write $c \in C$ to express the idea that the *object* $c$ is in the category $C$?
- Is there a symbol to express that $f: a \to b$ is a morphisms between objects of $C$? I guess even if the answer to the previous question was *yes*, $f \in C$ would be ambiguous because the reader wouldn't know whether $f$ is a morphism or an object.

As far as I know, the symbol $\in$ is a thing in set theory at least, but I'm not sure if it's appropriate for category theory, hence I'm asking this question.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

A common notation seems to be
$$c\in\operatorname{Ob}(C)$$
and $$f\in\operatorname{Mor}(C)$$
(or if you want to be more  specific: $f\in \operatorname{Mor}_C(a,b)$).

Using $\in$ in this context is okay because $\operatorname{Ob}(C)$ and $\operatorname{Mor}(C)$ are at least classes, though typically not sets.

Comment: +1 for the to-the-point answer. It seems one does not even require underlying collections to be classes even. We just need two predicates $\in Ob(C)$ and $\in Mor(C)$. When the objects and morphisms form classes, these predicates are given by the underlying set theory with classes. But, it works equally well when categories are axiomatised as 2-sorted first order language. Right? But I suppose most people are only concerned with categories based on set theory.

Comment: "... are at least classes, though typically not sets" is not universally correct. In particular in category theory NBG is not the best foundation, and it is much more common and useful to use ZFC + universes. In this system, everything is a set - but sets come in different sizes.

Comment: You can also use $f\in\vec{C}$, the category of arrows of $C$ whose objects are morphisms and morphisms are commutative squares.